# Send html table to a servlet to a jsp

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, html-table

How can I send html table to a servlet to a jsp?

In my Action class I have a table I want to send this table to my jsp with a `request.setAttributes("table",tableHtml);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using the above setAttribute you can retrieve it in a JSP like so:

```
<%= ((String)request.getAttribute("table"))%>
```